# Push Notification when I delete the app

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I have a question about the Push Notification:

I have my server where I store all of my device tokens and other information about the smartphone/tablet. When I delete the app, how do I know if the app was deleted, so that I can delete its information from my database server?

Comment: As an aside as I saw a similar problem: if the app allows a sign-in feature (and the user could log out to let a friend log in), you have to account for that too.  My friends recently discovered that Discord *didn't* and one person was seeing push notifications for a conversation *they did not have access to.*

Comment: But my app i can't implement the control by username. Are there another form to control when app is removed?

Comment: I don't know anything about how its programmed, I've only done the barest of bare iOS development.  I just thought I'd throw the warning flag in case it was relevant.  If it isn't relevant for you, that's fine.  If it's relevant for someone else who stumbles across this question in the future, then it was worth making.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apples feedback service will send a device not found message in which you can catch the response and delete from database. I've implemented this with mine. Feedback service works great. Even changes device id's if your device ID  expires in which case you catch that response and update your database.

Answer (score 3):

use the [Feedback Service](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Appendixes/BinaryProviderAPI.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH106-SW4) that Apple provides.